# Updating child instead of deleting it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Look at the entity -

```
class Person
{
   int id { get; set; };
   IList<PersonAddress> Addresses { set; get; }
   ...
}
```

Now while updating person from UI if I just remove some addresses from the list of address
then I wand to actually delete the address record from db. currently this is updating the address table setting **personId = NULL** and not deleting the address record. Does anyone know how to do this. may be some mapping issue.

Here I am adding whole `Person` class mapping file.

```
public class PersonMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Person>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Person> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Schema(Schemas.Common);
        mapping.Table("Person");

        mapping.Map(x => x.FirstName).Not.Nullable();
        mapping.Map(x => x.LastName).Not.Nullable();
        mapping.Map(x => x.DateOfBirth).Nullable();

        mapping.References(x => x.Title);
        mapping.References(x => x.Ethnicity);
        mapping.References(x => x.Language);
        mapping.References(x => x.Religion);
        mapping.References(x => x.Country);
        mapping.References(x => x.Gender).Not.Nullable();

        mapping.References(x => x.LoginDetail);

        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Addresses)
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonAddress_Person_PersonID")
            .Where("DeletedDate is null")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        mapping.HasMany(x => x.TelephoneNumbers)
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonTelephoneNumber_Person_PersonID")
            .Where("DeletedDate is null")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        mapping.HasMany(x => x.EmailAddresses)
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonEmailAddress_Person_PersonID")
            .Where("DeletedDate is null")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        mapping.References(x => x.Photograph);

        mapping.References(x => x.Signature);

        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Photographs)
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonPhotograph_Person_PersonID")
            .Where("DeletedDate is null")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Signatures)
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonSignature_Person_PersonID")
            .Where("DeletedDate is null")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        //mapping.HasMany(x => x.JobRoles)
        //    .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonJobRole_Person_PersonID");
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Skills)
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonSkill_Person");
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.SpokenLanguages)
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonSpokenLanguage_Person");
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.ForbiddenCentres)
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonForbiddenCentre_Person");
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Availabilities)
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonAvailability_Person");
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Qualifications)
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonQualification_Person");

        mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.PrimaryEmailAddress);
        mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.WorkAddress);
    }
}
```

This is for `PersonAddress` mapping:

```
public class PersonAddressMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<PersonAddress>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<PersonAddress> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Schema(Schemas.Common);
        mapping.Table("PersonAddress");
        mapping.References(x => x.Person);
        mapping.References(x => x.Address).Cascade.SaveUpdate().Not.Nullable();
        mapping.References(x => x.AddressType).Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a mapping issue so please post the mapping as well ta.

Comment: mapping.HasMany(x => x.Addresses)
                .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonAddress_Person_PersonID")
                .Where("DeletedDate is null")
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .Cascade.SaveUpdate();

Comment: This is the mapping file for Person class it looks it is already using Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()

Comment: And mapping for Address class is -   mapping.Schema(Schemas.Common);
            mapping.Table("PersonAddress");
            mapping.References(x => x.Person);
            mapping.References(x => x.Address).Cascade.SaveUpdate().Not.Nullable();
            mapping.References(x => x.AddressType).Not.Nullable();

Comment: I assume this is a bag mapping? Can you not just paste the whole mapping class for person?

Comment: @Rippo :  I have added the code for mapping file

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT: the fluent mapping added appended below*

Let's assume your mapping using `<bag>` looks like this:

```
<bag name="address" >
    <key column="PersonId" />
    <one-to-many class="Address"/>
</bag>
```

This is working, and instructing NHibernate to maintain `address` collection. If new object is added into the collection, its `PersonId` column will be updated with relationship to current Person. If some address is removed... its `PersonId` column will be set to null.

If we want more, we could use cascading:

```
<bag name="address" cascade="all-delete-orphan"
    <key column="PersonId" />
    <one-to-many class="Address"/>
</bag>
```

In this case, we do not care only about the relationship, but even about the items inside the collection. Check this mapping for more details: [6.2. Mapping a Collection](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping) (a small extract):

> (6) cascade (optional - defaults to none) enable operations to cascade to child entities

Now, when we remove the address instance from the collection, it will be also deleted from persistence. But, the steps to do that will be:

1. Update address and set the `PersonId` to NULL
2. Delete the address

To avoid that, we can add another mapping feature: inverse mapping. So, in case, that Address has mapping to Person (many-to-one) we can use this mapping (see `inverse="true"`):

```
<bag name="address" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
    <key column="PersonId" />
    <one-to-many class="Address"/>
</bag>
```

Which could be marked as the most efficient, because all the changes will be executed directly on the Address elements *(no intermediate steps)*

*NOTE: just a small cite from the 6.2:*

> Note: Large NHibernate bags mapped with inverse="false" are inefficient and should be avoided; NHibernate can't create, delete or update rows individually, because there is no key that may be used to identify an individual row.

EDIT: fluent mapping

base on the mapping you've included in the question, you should adjust the Address mapping this way:

```
...
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Addresses)
    .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_PersonAddress_Person_PersonID")
    .Where("DeletedDate is null")
    .Inverse() // this will cause the direct DELETE to be issued
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan() // this is the only Cascade which should be used
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks Ramdim for your answer I will check it and let you know!

Comment: I could see that I have already using the all-delete-orphan option for cascad.

Comment: As I've seen in your comments below your question, the issue could be in the incorrect cascade mapping. You are using Cascading on your Person Address-collection mapping: `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan() .Cascade.SaveUpdate();` This is wrong, I would say, because the last wins and overbeats the previous. Remove the last `SaveUpdate()` and leave just `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()`. Now all should work as expected

Comment: I removed the .Cascade.SaveUpdate() but still its updating Address with setting personId = NULL.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the mapping you'd need. Because until now it was correct to see insertion PersonId = NULL - because we were missing the `Inverse()` mapping. Append that to HasMany mapping, and NHibernate will be able to cascade the delete... in the inverse order. It will call "DELETE Address" only

Comment: I used your mapping but in this case it does not even fire update or delete...! no action performs.

Comment: Please, could you show me your Entities mapping? to me it starts to seem, that you have 3 entities in play. Address, Person and PersonAddress. Is it correct? Are you mapping Person-PersonAddress-Address? This is correct mapping but the pairing object (in the middle) is now target of our cascading.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43822/discussion-between-radim-kohler-and-sachin)