# Filter nested models on property in last node with NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I am using NHibernate with mapping by code.

I have three models: Solution, Installation and System. There are one-to-many relations between them. So that each Solution has a list of Installations, and each Installation has a list of Systems.

Each system has a property "Type", which can be "1" or "0".

I am trying to write a method in the Solution repository that will return all the Solutions, with their Installations with only the Systems of type "1".

I have tried the Where-keyword in the SystemMap but i get the same result with and without it. Then i tried a few different experiments with QueryOver(???) without success.

How do i go about to filter on information in the last node?

Thank to your answer, i have done the following implementation, but it results in a huge amount of Systems and Solutions. Maybe i have done something wrong?

The Maps are as follows:

```
    public SAPSolutionMap()
    {
        Id(t => t.YPID);

        Property(e => e.ShortName);
        Property(e => e.FullName);

        Bag(x => x.SapInstallations, colmap =>
        {
            colmap.Table("SAPInstallation");
            colmap.Key(x => x.Column("Solution"));
            colmap.Inverse(true);
            colmap.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
            colmap.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Join);
            colmap.Cascade(Cascade.None);
        }, map => map.OneToMany(m => m.Class(typeof(SAPInstallation))));
    }

    public SAPInstallationMap()
    {
        Id(t => t.InstallationNumber);

        Bag(x => x.SapSystems, colmap =>
        {
            colmap.Table("sapgui");
            colmap.Key(x => x.Column("Installation"));
            colmap.Inverse(true);
            colmap.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
            colmap.Cascade(Cascade.None);
            colmap.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Join);
            //colmap.Where("Type = 1");
        }, map => map.OneToMany(m => m.Class(typeof(SAPSystem))));

        ManyToOne(x => x.SapSolution, map =>
        {
            map.Column("Solution");
            map.NotNullable(true);
            map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
            map.Class(typeof(SAPSolution));
        });
    }

    public SAPSystemMap()
    {
        Id(t => t.ID, t => t.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        Property(e => e.Type);
        Property(e => e.ExplanationText);

        ManyToOne(x => x.SapInstallation, map =>
        {
            map.Column("Installation");
            map.NotNullable(true);
            map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
            map.Class(typeof(SAPInstallation));
        });
    }
```

And the Query:

```
    public IList<SAPSolution> GetProductionSystems()
    {
        SAPSystem syst = null;
        SAPInstallation installation = null;
        var subquery = QueryOver.Of(() => syst)
            .JoinQueryOver(x => x.SapInstallation, () => installation)
            .Where(() => syst.Type == 1)
            .Select(x => installation.SapSolution.YPID);

        // main Query 
        var query = Session.QueryOver<SAPSolution>()
            .WithSubquery
                .WhereProperty(root => root.YPID)
            .In(subquery);

        return query.List<SAPSolution>();
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General solution should be:

```
// this is a subquery (SELECT ....
System syst = null;
Installation installation = null;
var subquery = QueryOver.Of(() => syst)
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Installation, () => installation)
    .Where(() => syst.Type == 1)
    .Select(x => installation.Solution.ID)
;

// main Query 
var query = session.QueryOver<Solution>()    
    .WithSubquery
        .WhereProperty(root => root.ID)
    .In(subquery)
    ;

var list = query
   .Take(10)
   .Skip(10)
   .List<Solution>();
```

What we can see, that Solution, Installation and System

- `System` has property `Installation` *(`many-to-one`)*
- `Installation` has property `Solution` *(`many-to-one`)*

This is expect-able, because it goes side by side with one-to-many (it is the reverse mapping)

So, then we create `subquery`, which returns just solution ID's which belong to system with searched Type.

Main query is flat (the great benefit) and we can use paging on top of it.

*We would be able to do that even if there is only one way (one-to-many). But that will generate more complicated SQL query ... and does not make sense. In C# we can have both relations...*

EXTEND:

You did a great job. Your mapping and query is really cool. But there is one big but: LAZY is what we should/MUST use. Check this:

#### [NHibernate is lazy, just live with it,](http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it) by Ayende

So, our, collections cannot be FETCHING with a JOIN, because that will multiply the result (10 solutions * 100 installation * 10 systems == 10000 results)

```
Bag(x => x.SapSystems, colmap =>
{ 
    ...
    // THIS IS not good way
    colmap.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
    colmap.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Join);
```

We should use LAZY as possible. To avoid later 1 + N issue, we can use batch-fetching (for example check this)

- [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20970680/1679310)

So, our collections should be mapped like this:

```
Bag(x => x.SapSystems, colmap =>
{ 
    ...
    // THIS IS not good way
    colmap.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Lazy);
    colmap.BatchSize(100);
```

With this setting, **the query will really use only the root object** and related collections will be **loaded very effectively**

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift response. I will add the reverse mapping properties and test it.

Comment: It is very smart decision, believe me. Becuase, such relation simply exists (one-to-many have the many-to-one reversed end) and what's more, you **will gain a lot**. Becuase you can use **`.Inverse()`** mapping on your `HasMany()` and that will bring much more efficient SQL INSERT, UPDATE scripts. Maybe check other Q & A - http://stackoverflow.com/q/20755311/1679310

Comment: Hello again. I have tried implementing it and i think we are really close. I get more than 400 Solutions and 118000 Systems. I have only a fraction of that in the Database. Might we have missed a small detail somewhere in the queries?

Comment: Could you please, update your question with the latest code you have? The query and if it won't be clear, please append entities and their mapping. **I am sure we will make it** ;) *(because it seems, that you are joining the collections into root query... and that is wrong. My solution is - create subqeury and FLAT outer - root query, without any join to collections)*

Comment: I tried to describe the issue, added some links to interesting reading... and showed how to adjust the mapping to get very narrowed results. Hope it helps

Comment: You sir are a genius. I changed to lazy and added a batch(600), and now it only gets the production systems and only makes 8 queries (110 queries before). It takes 2.2s with a FindAll-implementation with a where.clause in the systems-bag in installations, and only 1.1s with your query. Thank you!

Comment: Really great to see that. Also please, do not forget that we do have paging. We can use our query and: `query.Skip(100).Take(25)` to reduce amount of data transferred... Enjoy mighty NHibernate